# Why Sindoor is offered to Lord Hanuman?

Tags: hanuman

I have seen orange statues of Lord Hanuman in temples. It is orange because of "Sindoor" on it. Why "Sindoor" is offered to Lord Hanuman?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When Hanuman saw Sita applying Sindoor (Vermillion) in her hair, he
>   asked the reason for the same. Sita replied that it was for long life
>   and well being of Lord Rama, her husband. Hanuman, the biggest devotee
>   of Rama thought if a pinch of sindoor in the hair can increase the
>   longevity of Lord Rama then why not apply on the entire body. He then
>   applied sindoor all over his body for Rama’s long life. Seeing this
>   innocence and unmatched devotion of Hanuman, Lord Rama gave him a
>   vardan (blessings) that whenever the name of devotion takes place,
>   Hanuman’s name will be taken first. Also, whoever will pay respect to
>   Hanuman on Tuesday, not only will his/her wishes come true but will
>   also be dear to Lord Rama himself.

[5 Lesser Known Facts About Lord Hanuman](http://indiaopines.com/lesser-known-facts-lord-hanuman/)

Comment: The source mentioned is empty.

Comment: I'm sorry, you might have undertaken good effort to answer, but This particular answer doesn't qualify as a proper answer by the Stack Exchange standards.

Answer (score 0):

Once Hanuman ji saw Sita Mata applying sindoor on her head in partition of hair. He asked Mata why she was applying sindoor. She told that sindoor is symbol of her love, her marriage and she does it for long life of long life. It also makes shree Ram happy.

Hanuman Ji thought that he also wants to make shri Ram Happy and wish for Long life of Shri Ram.

So, Bajrangbali ji applied Sindoor with Ghee on his body. This was Tuesday when it happened.

Hanuman ji went in front Shri Ram and Sita mata in the Shri Ram Darbar ( Court of Shri Ram )

Where everyone started laughing on Shri Hanuman, Shri Ram asked Hanuman ji the reason for applying sindoor on His whole body.

Hanuman ji told the reason of doing it.

Shri Ram was very happy and he gave blessings to Hanuman ji and Bhakt / who will workship Hanuman ji that Who so ever will worship Hanuman ji with red sindoor and chola or who will help to do so, all the wishes will come true for him / her. He will have blessings of Hanuman ji and Shri Ram too.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! You should cite authentic Hindu sources such as Ramayana, Puranas.

Comment: In yet another episode of Bhakthi and wisdom combined, Hanuma asked Rama a favour that he should be present in spirit wherever Ram was being worshipped. Sita asked Ram whether Ram understood the  real implication of Hanuma's immortality. Ram said yes,of course..  while granting him the boon.